# Prove $ \int_0^t 2X_s \ dX_s = X_t^2-X_0^2-\langle X, X\rangle_t $ WITHOUT Ito's formula

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Suppose $X$ is a continuous local martingale (on some complete filtered probability space). Then I want to prove that
$$
\int_0^t 2X_s \ dX_s = X_t^2-X_0^2-\langle X, X\rangle_t
$$
where $\langle X , X \rangle$ denotes the quadratic variation process of $X$.

One way to go about this is using Ito's formula but I want to see if I can give a direct proof of this just using properties of the stochastic integral.

---

What I have thought about so far is that by definition of the quadratic variation process the above yields that
$$
\int_0^t 2X_s \ dX_s - X_0^2
$$
is a continuous local martingale. Maybe this could be used along with the fact that the quadratic variation process is unique to show the relation?

It almost also looks like that $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ could play a role. Maybe this would lead to too many terms but some of them could be indistinguashable from 0 (by showing they were both a continuous local martingale and a finite variation process).

---

The textbook I have is "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus" by Jean-Francois Le Gall so any result prior to the section on Ito's formula is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you were almost there. Just use
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\int_0^tX_s\,dX_s&=\lim_{\max\limits_i|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{t_{i-1}}(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\langle X,X\rangle_t&=\lim_{\max\limits_i|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{t_i}- X_{t_{i-1}})^2\\\tag{2}
&=\lim_{\max\limits_i|t_i-t_{i-1}|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{t_i}(X_{t_i}- X_{t_{i-1}})-\int_0^tX_s\,dX_s\,.
\end{align}
The sum in the first term of (2) is
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^nX_{t_i}(X_{t_i}- X_{t_{i-1}})&=\sum_{i=1}^nX_{t_i}^2- X_{t_{i-1}}^2+X_{t_{i-1}}^2-X_{t_i}X_{t_{i-1}}\\&=X_t^2-X_0^2-\sum_{i=1}^nX_{t_{i-1}}(X_{t_i}- X_{t_{i-1}})\,.
\end{align}
By (1) this is $X_t^2-X_0^2-\int_0^tX_s\,dX_s$ in the limit.

Altogether we have

$$
\langle X,X\rangle_t=X_t^2-X_0^2-2\int_0^tX_s\,dX_s\,.
$$